# How to show horizontal Custom Radio Buttons in a Card View

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on the front-end of an e-commerce system which has a card view. I have to show radio buttons in horizontal custom style with different colors

I put radio buttons in the card and also customize but problem is that when apply custom style it's not working horizontally.

HTML

```
    <div class="card-body ">
       <span style="color: #B4B4B4"><h5><b>Color</b></h5></span>
           <form>
               <label class="radio-inline contain">
               <input type="radio checkbox" name="optradio" >
               <span class="checkmark"></span>
               </label>
               <label class="radio-inline contain">
               <input type="radio checkbox" name="optradio">
               <span class="checkmark"></span>
               </label>
               <label class="radio-inline contain">
               <input type="radio checkbox" name="optradio">
               <span class="checkmark"></span>
               </label>
           </form>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
 /* Customize the label (the container) */
.contain {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default radio button */
.contain input {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom radio button */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.contain:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */
.contain input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */
.contain input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */
.contain .checkmark:after {
  top: 9px;
  left: 9px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}
```

Radio buttons are vertical in single color but require horizontal and multi color

Comment: which bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: I am using bootstrap4 for it. It's working good on a page but in the card, it may be conflicted with any other class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an `input` type that is *both* `radio` and `checkbox`.

If you simply make use of `radio`, then your example works as expected:

```css
/* Customize the label (the container) */
.contain {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default radio button */
.contain input {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom radio button */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.contain:hover input~.checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */
.contain input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */
.contain input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */
.contain .checkmark:after {
  top: 9px;
  left: 9px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card-body ">
  <span style="color: #B4B4B4"><h5><b>Color</b></h5></span>
  <form>
    <label class="radio-inline contain">
       <input type="radio" name="optradio">
       <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline contain">
       <input type="radio" name="optradio">
       <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline contain">
       <input type="radio" name="optradio">
       <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the issue it was ``class="checkbox"`` but still it does not resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

put this code in place of your code

```css
.contain {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default radio button */
.contain input {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom radio button */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.contain:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */
.contain input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */
.contain input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */
.contain .checkmark:after {
  top: 9px;
  left: 9px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}
.all_radio{
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body ">
   <span style="color: #B4B4B4"><h5><b>Color</b></h5></span>
       <form>
        <div class="all_radio">
           <label class="radio-inline contain">
           <input type="radio" name="optradio" >
           <span class="checkmark"></span>
           </label>
           <label class="radio-inline contain">
           <input type="radio" name="optradio">
           <span class="checkmark"></span>
           </label>
           <label class="radio-inline contain">
           <input type="radio" name="optradio">
           <span class="checkmark"></span>
           </label>          
        </div>
       </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .contain {
                display: inline-block;
                position: relative;
                padding-left: 35px;
                margin-bottom: 12px;
                cursor: pointer;
                font-size: 22px;
                -webkit-user-select: none;
                -moz-user-select: none;
                -ms-user-select: none;
                user-select: none;
            }
            .contain input {
                opacity: 0;
                cursor: pointer;
                height: 0;
                width: 0;
            }
            .checkmark {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                height: 25px;
                width: 25px;
                background-color: blue;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
            .checkmark.one {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                height: 25px;
                width: 25px;
                background-color: green;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
            .checkmark.two {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                height: 25px;
                width: 25px;
                background-color: red;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
            .contain:hover input ~ .checkmark {
                background-color: blue;
            }
            .contain:hover input ~ .checkmark.one {
                background-color: green;
            }
            .contain:hover input ~ .checkmark.two {
                background-color: red;
            }
            .contain input:checked ~ .checkmark {
                background-color: blue;
            }
            .contain input:checked ~ .checkmark.one {
                background-color: green;
            }
            .contain input:checked ~ .checkmark.two {
                background-color: red;
            }
            .checkmark:after {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                display: none;
            }
            .contain input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
                display: block;
            }
            .contain .checkmark:after {
                top: 9px;
                left: 9px;
                width: 8px;
                height: 8px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                background: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="card-body">
        <span style="color: #707070; font-size: 18px;"><h5><b>Color</b></h5></span>
        <form>
            <label class="radio-inline contain">
                <input type="radio" name="optradio" >
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline contain">
                <input type="radio" name="optradio">
                <span class="checkmark one"></span>
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline contain">
                <input type="radio" name="optradio">
                <span class="checkmark two"></span>
            </label> 
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I try it but the same issue is here